# Create common context menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In my app I have many grids (Infragistics).  I would like to create a context menu that will implement many of the common functions ie: delete, save layout, etc. and if a specific grid needs more than the common functions be able to add to the menu for that grid.  I would like to create one context menu and not have to repeat the same code throughout project.

I have no idea on how to accomplish this. Possible?  Example xaml and/or code will be helpful.

Thanks a bunch,

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attempted to do similar things is the past (not with a context menu but with a listview).  While I never got it 100% working, as I couldn't get certain items to bind properly, I believe the way forward would be as follows;

- Create a Context Menu 'style', perhaps in a separate resource dictionary. Here you would design the elements that ALL context menu's will hold.
- When you require a more customised context menu, apply the basic context menu style defined in the previous step to your element and then use the [BasedOn attribute](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-the-basedon-style-property) to extend this context menu with custom items within this specific element.

Apologies for not including example XAML but I am on a mobile device and therefore cannot contruct XAML very well at all.

Hope this helps to some degree

Comment: That is what I did. Except instead of using BasedOn I added customized items on the contextShow event.